# WPF toolkit distribution

Tags: wpf, distribution, toolkit

My app uses WPF Toolkit (http://wpf.codeplex.com). Can anyone tell me what's the proper way of distributing my app ?

1) I can just dump the WPFTookit.dll (copied from the WPFToolkit installer) into my app folder.

2) I cannot distribute the dll directly. My installer must execute WPFToolkit installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [license](http://wpf.codeplex.com/license).  You can distribute it any way you want, but you must retain the copyright and license notices in your distribution.